# Update with subquery vs Update with join - Which is better in performance

Tags: sql, performance, postgresql, join, subquery

In a *Postgres* database, are the two following queries equivalent in **performance**? Everyone says "joins are always faster than subqueries", but does the *Postgres* query planner optimize subqueries into joins *behind the scenes*?

**Query 1:**

```
UPDATE table_a
SET col_1 = 'a fixed value'
WHERE col_2 IN (
    SELECT col_2 FROM table_b
);
```

*Explain Plan:*

```
Update on table_a  (cost=0.00..9316.10 rows=1 width=827)
  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.00..9316.10 rows=1 width=827)
        ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..9287.20 rows=1 width=821)
        ->  Index Scan using idx_table_b on table_b  (cost=0.00..14.45 rows=1 width=14)
              Index Cond: (col_2 = (table_a.col_2)::numeric)
```

**Query 2:**

```
UPDATE table_a ta
SET col_1 = 'a fixed value'
FROM table_b tb
WHERE ta.col_2 = tb.col_2;
```

*Explain Plan:*

```
Update on table_a ta  (cost=0.00..9301.67 rows=1 width=827)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..9301.67 rows=1 width=827)
        ->  Seq Scan on table_a ta  (cost=0.00..9287.20 rows=1 width=821)
        ->  Index Scan using idx_table_b on table_b tb  (cost=0.00..14.45 rows=1 width=14)
              Index Cond: (col_2 = (ta.col_2)::numeric)
```

I believe they are equivalent in results *(Please alert me if I'm wrong)*. I have tried several **explain plans** with large sets of data. It seems they are equivalent in performance, both when updating full table and when restricting `table_a.col_2` to a small subset.

I want to be sure I'm not missing something. If they are equivalent, which would you choose and why?

Comment: Are they functionally same? In the first case only the matching rows will be updated, other rows will retain their values. In the second case, non-matching rows will become `NULL`

Comment: @hashbrown **Incorrect.** I just tested it - non-matching rows will **not** become `NULL`. You must be confusing with the third possible construct: `UPDATE table_a SET col_1 = (SELECT 'a fixed value' FROM table_b where table_a.col_2 = table_b.col_2)`. In this construct, yes, non-matching rows **will** become `NULL` _and_ `col_2` must be unique.

Comment: If you've been looking at explain output, please include it! Also, provide useful table definitions and dummy data to match your queries so we don't have to make that stuff up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> does the Postgres query planner optimize subqueries into joins behind the scenes?

Usually, yes.

Don't guess, look at the query plans.

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (col_1 text, col_2 integer );
CREATE TABLE table_b (col_2 integer);
INSERT INTO table_b(col_2) VALUES (1),(2),(4),(NULL);
INSERT INTO table_a (col_1, col_2) VALUES ('a fixed value', 2), ('a fixed value', NULL), ('some other value', 2);
ANALYZE table_a;
ANALYZE table_b;
```

compare:

```
regress=> explain UPDATE table_a
SET col_1 = 'a fixed value'
WHERE col_2 IN (
    SELECT col_2 FROM table_b
);
                                QUERY PLAN                                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on table_a  (cost=1.09..2.15 rows=2 width=16)
   ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=1.09..2.15 rows=2 width=16)
         Hash Cond: (table_a.col_2 = table_b.col_2)
         ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=10)
         ->  Hash  (cost=1.04..1.04 rows=4 width=10)
               ->  Seq Scan on table_b  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=10)
(6 rows)

regress=> explain UPDATE table_a ta
regress-> SET col_1 = 'a fixed value'
regress-> FROM table_b tb
regress-> WHERE ta.col_2 = tb.col_2;
                                 QUERY PLAN                                  
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on table_a ta  (cost=1.07..2.14 rows=1 width=16)
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.07..2.14 rows=1 width=16)
         Hash Cond: (tb.col_2 = ta.col_2)
         ->  Seq Scan on table_b tb  (cost=0.00..1.04 rows=4 width=10)
         ->  Hash  (cost=1.03..1.03 rows=3 width=10)
               ->  Seq Scan on table_a ta  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=3 width=10)
(6 rows)
```

See? Same plan. The subquery has been transformed into a join.

It's usually cleaner to express it with `EXISTS` rather than `IN`. This is much more important for `NOT IN` vs `NOT EXISTS`, where they're semantically different in the face of nulls, so it's a good habit anyway. You'd write:

```
UPDATE table_a a
SET col_1 = 'a fixed value'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table_b b WHERE b.col_2 = a.col_2);
```

This will *also* tend to produce the same plan, but it's a bit nicer IMO - not least because if it *doesn't* plan down to a join, a correlated subquery is generally less horrible than a giant `IN` list scan.

Comment: Yes, the explain outputs are very similar with `Update > Nested Loop Semi Join > Seq Scan > Index Scan` for **Q1** and `Update > Nested Loop > Seq Scan > Index Scan` for **Q2**. I'm not sure what `Semi Join` is but it's the only difference. I'll update the question with text output.

Comment: Super late reply, but for anyone reading this in the future a `Semi Join` is like a join that only looks for whether you get a match - it returns after the first match instead of combining all the matching records like a regular `Join` would.   Because of this, it doesn't duplicate the records you actually care about if there's multiple matches.

Answer (score 1):

**IN:**

Returns true if a specified value matches any value in a subquery or a list.

**Exists:**

Returns true if a subquery contains any rows.

**Join:**

Joins 2 resultsets on the joining column.

---

If the joining column is `UNIQUE` then `join` in faster .

If it's not, then `IN is faster than JOIN on DISTINCT`.

See this article in my blog for performance details for Microsoft SQL Server, which might also be relevant to PostgreSQL:

- [**`IN` vs. `JOIN` vs. `EXISTS`** in Microsoft SQL Server](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/)

Comment: Thanks for the article. PostgreSQL query planner might behave differently, and that's what I want to know.

Comment: That's not the most relevant article, as it's for a completely different database engine. When you are following the [tag:SQL] tag, please keep in mind that it means "Structured Query Language (SQL)", not "Microsoft SQL Server", and answer accordingly.